# Find Processes without Application (.NET)

Tags: .net, process

We have an issue where a Windows app will end abnormally.  It disappears from the Applications tab in Task Manager but still shows up in the Processes tab.  Upon start-up, we'd like the app to identify those orphaned processes and terminate them.  The trouble is, I can't find a way to identify them.  I tried using the .MainWindowTitle property of the Process class, but the orphaned processes still have the same title as functioning processes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's not exactly abnormal.  Entirely common if you use Application.DoEvents() in your code for example.  Or start a worker thread that won't quit.  Fix the problem, don't try to put a band-aid on it.

Comment: I agree with you, but that's above my pay grade.  The powers that be want the bandaid.